# Typescript: how to search a const array?

Tags: typescript

I just have a normal array.

- I want the string literals out of an array for use in a type
- I want to search the array with `.includes()`

These two things seem to be incompatible for some reason... How should I do this?

```
const x = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;
type somethingElse = typeof x[number]; // 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
x.includes('foo' as string);           // string not assignable to 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=29#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDA2gcgIZoDQzQIxz2DQF0YMIZRIoBuAKCgE8AHAUxghAFt2oAFgEswAcwCiAGwidkLDiABm8FGACuPfOwBOpOjAD0BvFhgAfPIXPE0DOADoRwSWoAm7CAAo0ikCDQUVNDaIqIAlHRAA)

Comment: Why you have "as const" in 1st line ?

Comment: to get the type `'a' | 'b' | 'c'` on line 2.  Without it the array is typed as `string[]` and I can't get the literal values out

Comment: I'm confused; it's doing exactly what you are telling it to. You've told it that `x` can only be `['a', 'b', 'c']`. You then  try to search for `'foo'` and it's throwing an error, because `'foo'`, and more generically, `string`, cannot be `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey -- I want the type.  I want to search it.  How do I do both without TS complaining?

Comment: You separate your concerns. You create a type that's separate from your array. Search the array, not the type.

Comment: I'm obviously trying to prevent needing to create and maintain two identical lists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast `x` to a `string[]` for the purposes of searching it.

```typescript
const x = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;
type somethingElse = typeof x[number]; // 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
(x as readonly string[]).includes('foo'); // false
```